# Is there a way to script diagrams in SQL 2000 (or save them another way)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, diagram

It's possible to create digrams in SQL Server 2000 that can be useful to show the relationships between tables.  The problem we run into is that when somebody refreshes our development database, the diagrams get lost.  We can load tables, stored procedures, views, etc. with SQL scripts, but we have to create the diagrams by hand.

Is there a way to script out the diagrams?  Or can they be saved outside of the database some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done for SQL Server 2005 - see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ScriptDiagram2005.aspx).

And info. on SQL Server 2000 - [here](http://bytes.com/forum/thread81534.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you have Visio you can use the "Reverse Engineer" to diagram the DB.